# Handle Key-Error whilst scraping

Tags: python, error-handling, web-scraping, data-extraction

I am currently working on a script to scrape data from [ClinicalTrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/). To do this I have written the following script:

```
def clinicalTrialsGov (id):
    url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + id + "?displayxml=true"
    data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
    studyType = data.study_type.text
    if studyType == 'Interventional':
        allocation = data.allocation.text
        interventionModel = data.intervention_model.text
        primaryPurpose = data.primary_purpose.text
        masking = data.masking.text
        enrollment = data.enrollment.text
    officialTitle = data.official_title.text
    condition = data.condition.text
    minAge = data.eligibility.minimum_age.text
    maxAge = data.eligibility.maximum_age.text
    gender = data.eligibility.gender.text
    healthyVolunteers = data.eligibility.healthy_volunteers.text
    armType = []
    intType = []
    for each in data.findAll('intervention'):
        intType.append(each.intervention_type.text)
    for each in data.findAll('arm_group'):
        armType.append(each.arm_group_type.text)
    citedPMID = tryExceptCT(data, '.results_reference.PMID')
    citedPMID = data.results_reference.PMID
    print(citedPMID)
    return officialTitle, studyType, allocation, interventionModel, primaryPurpose, masking, enrollment, condition, minAge, maxAge, gender, healthyVolunteers, armType, intType
```

However, the following script won't always work as not all studies will have all items (ie. a `KeyError` will occur). To resolve this, I could simply wrap each statement in a try-except catch, like this:

```
try:
  studyType = data.study_type.text
except:
  studyType = ""
```

but it seems a bad way to implement this. What's a better/cleaner solution?

Comment: The website provides you a way to download the data without scraping: https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/resources/download

Comment: @Blender See _Display a Single Record in XML_ section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question. Before I address it, let me say that you should consider changing the second parameter to the BeautifulSoup (BS) constructor from `lxml` to `xml`. Otherwise, BS does not flag the parsed markup as XML (to verify this for yourself, access the `is_xml` attribute on the `data` variable in your code).

You can avoid generating an error when attempting to access a non-existent element by passing a list of desired element names to the `find_all()` method:

```
subset = ['results_reference','allocation','interventionModel','primaryPurpose','masking','enrollment','eligibility','official_title','arm_group','condition']

tag_matches = data.find_all(subset)
```

Then, if you want to get a specific element from the list of Tags without iterating through it, you can convert it to a dict using the Tag names as keys:

```
tag_dict = dict((tag_matches[i].name, tag_matches[i]) for i in range(0, len(tag_matches)))
```

Comment: This works really well, thanks. However, some records (eg. [NCT02170532](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT02170532)) will have multiple intervention types and your code wont show all of them. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Yeah, well, I have to admit that the generator in the third line could be just as expensive as iterating over the list and checking for string equality on each element. As far as handling multiple intervention types, I'll leave that as an exercise for you. It should be pretty straight forward, given what you already know.